# Rails4 strong parameters type checking

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I am migrating to Rails4, and I encounter some troubles with the new "strong parameters" feature.

In my `UsersController`, i have:

```
params.require(:user).permit(:email, :name, :password, :accept_mail_news)
```

But if somebody pass incorrect parameters, like

```
{"user"=>"a dummy string"}
```

Instead of receiving a 400, he will receive a 500:

```
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `permit' for "a dummy string":String>
```

Is there a generic way to "check types" in strong parameters, or must I do it all manually ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way I can think of is to check if `params.require(:user)` [`respond_to?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-respond_to-3F) `permit` method.  Something like:

```
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb

def user_params
  if params.require(:user).respond_to?(:permit) 
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :name, :password, :accept_mail_news)
  else
    # Raise error, notify users...
  end
end
```

[`try`](http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/Object%3atry) could also be an option using which would return `nil` if `params.require(:user)` does not respond to `permit`:

```
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb

def user_params
  params.require(:user).try(:permit, :email, :name, :password, :accept_mail_news)
end
```

Comment: If there is no automatic way to do this, I guess it's a good option

Answer (score 0):

The structure of the parameters you receive is determined by the HTML that is running in the page at time of submission which in turn is determined by the view (and supporting code) you've implemented for your app. If you design your view properly, then the `user` value will always be a hash and you won't have the problem you describe.

Comment: My application is an api, i do not control the params